# CERTBOT can't find config file in docker container

Tags: docker, lets-encrypt, certbot

Two months ago, I set up a website with SSL thanks to Let's Encrypt. The details of how I did it are now quite blurry.

The site is hosted inside several docker containers (nginx, PHP, MySQL). There is a certbot container which should perform the renewal of the SSL certificate. This container is launched once a week and aborts immediately.

I have checked the logs and found this error. My research were unsuccessful and I have no idea what file certbot is complaining about.

```
usage:
  certbot [SUBCOMMAND] [options] [-d DOMAIN] [-d DOMAIN] ...

Certbot can obtain and install HTTPS/TLS/SSL certificates.  By default,
it will attempt to use a webserver both for obtaining and installing the
certificate.
certbot: error: Unable to open config file: certonly -n --webroot --webroot-path=/var/lib/challenge --email contact@**********.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d www.**********.com --key-type ecdsa. Error: No such file or directory
```

Do you have any idea of the problem?
Thanks in advance,

EDIT:
The contents of /etc/letsencrypt are

```
accounts       archive        cli.ini        csr            keys           live           renewal        renewal-hooks
```

Inside cli.ini, I have :

```
key-type = ecdsa
elliptic-curve = secp384r1
rsa-key-size = 4096
email = contact@attom.eu
authenticator = webroot
webroot-path = /var/lib/challenge
agree-tos = true
```

The docker-compose.yml contains :

```
version: '3'

services:

    nginx:
        build: ./nginx
        container_name: nginx
        restart: unless-stopped
        depends_on:
          - php
        networks:
            - app-network
        volumes:
            - {{ mounted_dir_app }}/public:/var/www/html:ro
            - certbotdata:/etc/letsencrypt:ro
            - challenge:/home/challenge
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        env_file:
            - .env
            - ".env.$ENV"
        healthcheck:
            test: curl -IsLk $$SITE_URL | head -n 1 | grep -q -e ^HTTP -e 200
            start_period: 30s
            interval: 10s
            timeout: 3s
            retries: 5

    php:
        #skip

    mysql:
        #skip

    certbot:
        depends_on:
            nginx:
                condition: service_healthy
        build: 
            context: ./certbot
            args:
                - "ENV=$ENV"
        container_name: certbot
        env_file:
            - .env
            - ".env.$ENV"
        volumes:
            - certbotdata:/etc/letsencrypt
            - challenge:/var/lib/challenge

networks:
    app-network:
        driver: bridge

volumes:
    dbdata:
    certbotdata:
    challenge:
```

Edit:
The CERTBOT Dockerfile is

```
ARG ENV

FROM certbot/certbot as cert-prod
CMD  certonly -n --webroot --webroot-path=/var/lib/challenge --email contact@**********.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d www.**********.com --key-type ecdsa

FROM alpine as cert-dev
RUN apk update && apk add openssl
CMD mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.**********.com          && \
    openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048     \
    -subj "/C=**/ST=**********/L=**********"            \
    -keyout /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.**********.com/privkey.pem -out /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.**********.com/fullchain.pem

FROM cert-${ENV}
```

Comment: I have an idea: Maybe it's unable to open the config file. What's in `/etc/letsencrypt/` and did you check [the docs](https://eff-certbot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/using.html#configuration-file), especially where it says "By default no cli.ini file is created" ?

Comment: Edit your question and show the Dockerfile and the command that starts the container. My guess is that you are mapping a directory in the host that is shared between containers. You forgot to attach the host directory. Compare 
the startup command with the other containers. https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/

Comment: To Daniel W.: I didn't have a cli.ini created. I, first, tried with an empty version of it, then I tried with the version shown in the question. Still having the same message.

Comment: To John Hanley: I do have a shared volume between two containers. Your remark make me realise that the challenge volume was read only from the nginx volume.
Still having the same message.

Comment: @DanielW. Forgot to ping you, sry.

Comment: @JohnHanley Forgot to ping you, sry.

Comment: Show the section where **certbot** is being executed. The error message looks like the entire command line is being treated as a file name.

Comment: @JohnHanley This dockerfile is a multi-stage dockerfile, the aim is to keep only one of the two stages depending of the environnement (indicated in the ENV argument).